# Invoking setter method when modifying object's fields

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, setter, flutter-hive

I have a preferences class which I want to store and read to/from a database, reading the preferences happen a lot in my application so I want to store an intstance of this preferences object alive in the app. This part is okay but when writing the prefrences back to the database when any changes occur is problematic. I want to access and modify my preferences like a regular object and let the reading/writing on the DB side happen in the background. So I wrote getters and setters for the instance of my object and made it like a Singleton, reading part is okay but when modifying the object the setter isn't invoked.

```
late final preferencesData _preferences;

preferencesData get preferences {
    if (_preferences == null) {
      _preferences = preferencesDatabase.get('0',defaultValue: preferencesData(datatypeVersion: appVersion, creationTime: DateTime.now()))!;
    }
    print('Preferences read');
    return _preferences;
  }
set preferences(preferencesData val){
    preferencesDatabase.put('0', val);
    print('Preferences set');
  }
```

In the app when running
`print(prefrences.UIsize);`
this gets printed

```
Preferences read
1.3
```

But when running

```
preferences.UIsize = 5.0;
print(prefrences.UIsize);
```

this gets printed

```
Preferences read
Preferences read
5.0
```

where as I expect

```
Preferences read
Preferences set
Preferences read
5.0
```

My class definition is like:

```
import 'package:app/3_Datas/1_HiveDataTypes/ColorSerializer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'preferencesDataType.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
@HiveType(typeId: 5)
class preferencesData extends HiveObject{
  @HiveField(0) List<double> versionUpdateList = [1.0];
  @HiveField(1) double datatypeVersion;
  @HiveField(2) String entryCode = '0';
  @HiveField(3) DateTime creationTime;
  @HiveField(4) String username = 'user';
  @HiveField(5) List<String> yayinlar = ['Yayın ekle+'];
  @HiveField(6) double UItextSize = 1.0;
  @HiveField(7) double UIappSize = 1.0;
  @ColorSerialiser()
  @HiveField(8) List<Color> backgroundColors = [
    Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 200, 243),Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 124, 201),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 45, 113),Color.fromARGB(255, 82, 185, 99),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 70, 248),Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 62, 88),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 45, 113),Color.fromARGB(255, 82, 185, 99),
    Colors.transparent,Colors.transparent
    ];
  @HiveField(9) bool dersModu = false;
  @HiveField(10) bool isWelcome = true;
  @HiveField(11) bool hasVersionChanged= true;
  @HiveField(12) Map<String,int> konuProgress = {};
  @HiveField(13) Map<String,dynamic> dataCursors = {};
  
  preferencesData(
    {
      required this.datatypeVersion,
      required this.creationTime,
    })
  {

  }
```

How can I do this without having to manually write to the DB inside the app code? I am using flutter-hive as DB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The setter that you defined is for the `preferences` itself, not for its member (in this case, `UIsize`). Please include the class definition of `preferencesData` so we can help with the solution.

Comment: Also it might be a good idea to follow [Dart naming convention](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/style) to remove confusion between types and other identifiers.

Comment: I have added the class definition as to your request @DhafinRayhan